# "A ist B" same as "B ist A"?

Tags: meaning

Haben diese Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung?

> Hunde sind zivilisierte Wölfe.
>   Zivilisierte Wölfe sind Hunde.

Zweites Beispiel:

> Erdbeerkuchen ist Kuchen mit Erdbeeren.
>   Kuchen mit Erdbeeren ist Erdbeerkuchen.

Nachtrag:

Danke für eure Antworten, ich habe jetzt erst richtig begriffen, was mich erst zu dieser Frage führte. Ich hatte woanders geschrieben "Zivilisierte Wölfe sind Hunde", jedoch wurde ich dort berichtigt, dass es korrekt "Hunde sind zivilisierte Wölfe" heißt. Da, sollte man Wölfe z.B. nochmal zivilisieren mit unterschiedlichen Methoden, etwas anderes als Hunde entstehen könnte.

Also Hunde sind zwar eine Unterklasse von Wölfen.
Aber zivilisierte Wölfe werden nicht `immer` zu Hunden.

Deshalb sollte es wohl korrekt im Umkehrschluß heißen:

> Zivilisierte Wölfe können Hunde sein.

?

Comment: Ja, nennt sich Gleichsetzungsnominativ.

Comment: *Alle Männer sind Schweine <> Schweine sind alle Männer* ist auch ein Prädikativ, aber nicht umkehrbar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a logic question not specifically pertaining to the German language

Comment: @tofro Es geht hier nicht um die Logik an sich, sondern um die Frage,
was ein deutscher Satz logisch gesehen bedeutet, sprich, um
die Semantik der deutschen Sprache. Das ist hier on-topic.

Comment: @lama12345 Zu dem Nachtrag:
Wenn Du den Satz sprachlich umkehren willst, ohne den Sinn zu
veränderrn, bekommst Du *"Zu den zivilisierten Wölfen zählen die*
(oder präziser: *alle*) *Hunde.*"

Comment: @uwe "x ist y" gibt es in allen mir bekannten Sprachen. Und in allen bedeutet es dasselbe.

Comment: @tofro Im Deutschen gibt es die Möglichkeit "Subjekt ist Gleichsetzungsnominativ" und
"Gleichsetzungsnominativ ist Subjekt"
(was einen Unterschied macht, da ein impliziter Allquantor
vor dem Subjekt steht). 
Im Englischen auch?

Comment: @uwe Das ist schon richtig. Nur ist das nicht gefragt.

Answer (score 7):

Die Verben

- sein
- werden
- heißen
- bleiben
- gelten als
- sich fühlen als

und einige andere können als Ergänzung eine Nominalphrase haben, die im Nominativ steht. Statt »Nominativobjekt« ist aber der Begriff »Gleichsetzungsnominativ« geläufiger.

Nun hat Deutsch die ganz allgemeine Eigenschaft, dass Subjekt und Objekte relativ folgenlos den Platz tauschen können:

> Ich liebe dich. Dich liebe ich.
>   Ich gehöre dir. Dir gehöre ich.

Das ist auch im Fall des Gleichsetzungsnominativ möglich:

> 1. Ich bin Rechtshänder.
> 2. Rechtshänder bin ich.

In dem obigen Rechtshänder -Beispiel kann man leicht argumentieren, dass »ich« in beiden Versionen das Subjekt und »Rechtshänder« das Objekt im Nominativ ist, weil »Rechtshänder« unbestimmt ist (würde man einen Artikel davor setzen, müsste das ein unbestimmter Artikel sein), während mit »ich« eine ganz konkrete Person gemeint ist (nämlich der Sprecher oder Autor).

Aber:

> 1. Der Mann mit dem roten Schal ist der Mörder.
> 2. Der Mörder ist der Mann mit dem roten Schal.

Hier sind beide Ergänzungen des Verbs bestimmt, und haben daher gleichermaßen den Anspruch, als Subjekt angesehen zu werden. Und tatsächlich ist in diesem Beispiel sowohl in (1) als auch in (2) unklar, ob »der Mann mit dem roten Schal« oder »der Mörder« das Subjekt oder das Objekt ist.

Da die übliche Satzstellung jene ist, in der das Subjekt am Beginn des Satzes steht, wird man daher in (1) eher »der Mann mit dem roten Schal« mit dem Subjekt identifizieren, in (2) hingegen erscheint eher »der Mörder« als das Subjekt. Und das führt dazu, dass (1) und (2) unterschiedlich interpretiert werden:

1. Wir betrachten einen Mann der einen roten Schal trägt, und halten ihn anfangs vielleicht sogar für sympathisch. Durch diesen Satz erfahren wir aber etwas über den Schalträger, nämlich dass er der Mörder ist.
2. Wir untersuchen einen Mordfall und wissen, dass es einen Mörder geben muss. Wir wissen anfangs aber nicht, wer der Mörder ist. Durch diesen Satz erfahren wir aber, wer der Mörder ist: Es ist der Mann mit dem roten Schal.

Selbstverständlich ist bei entsprechendem Kontext auch die umgekehrte Interpretation möglich, der hier geschilderte Fall ist aber der naheliegendere.

---

Kommen wir zu deinen Beispielen.

**Hunde und Wölfe**

In deinen Beispielen sind jeweils beide Ergänzungen unbestimmt. Im ersten Beispiel sind nicht ganz bestimmte Hunde gemeint, sondern alle. Und es zwar nur einige Wölfe gemeint (nämlich jene, die zivilisiert sind), von diesen aber auch alle. Links und rechts liegt das gleiche Ausmaß an Bestimmtheit vor (nämlich: unbestimmt). Bei der Suche nach dem Subjekt können wir uns also nur an der Reihenfolge im Satz orientieren, und genau das führt, wie oben im Fall des Mörders gezeigt, dazu, dass die beiden Sätze unterschiedlich interpretiert werden können:

1. Wir untersuchen Hunde, und versuchen etwas über Hunde herauszufinden. Durch den Satz »Hunde sind zivilisierte Wölfe« erfahren wir, dass alle Hunde Wölfe mit einer bestimmten Eigenschaft sind.
2. Wir sind an Wölfen interessiert, aber nicht an allen, sondern nur an zivilisierten. Wir wollen etwas über alle zivilisierte Wölfe herausfinden, und erfahren durch den Satz »Zivilisierte Wölfe sind Hunde«, dass die Tiere, für die wir uns interessieren, Hunde sind.

**Erdbeerkuchen**

Hier gilt im Prinzip auch alles gleich wie bei den Hunden und Wölfen, aber es gibt einen wesentlichen Unterschied: Wir vergleichen jetzt nicht mehr verschiedene Dinge (Mann mit Schal - Mörder, Hunde - Wölfe), sondern wir vergleichen jetzt gleiche Dinge, nämlich Kuchen mit Kuchen. Das ist bereits so nahe an der vollkommenen Identität wie man sie in

> Ein Stuhl ist ein Stuhl.

findet, dass die Argumentation, die noch bei *Mann mit Schal - Mörder* und bei *Hunde - Wölfe* gegriffen hat, hier weitgehend ins Leere geht.

Daher würde ich im Kuchen-Beispiel sagen, dass beide Versionen genau gleich zu interpretieren sind.

Comment: Also, wenn schon, dann Rose - und nicht Stuhl ;)

Answer (score 4):

Wer einen deutschen Satz der Form

> Bageduls sind Gamelafs.

formuliert, der meint üblicherweise

> Alle Bageduls sind Gamelafs.

auch wenn er das Wort "alle" nicht ausspricht.
Entsprechendes gilt für den Singular: Der Satz

> (Ein) Bagedul ist (ein) Gamelaf.

bedeutet üblicherweise

> Jeder Bagedul ist (ein) Gamelaf.

Für einen Logiker ist das ein *impliziter Allquantor*:
*Allquantor*, weil eine Aussage über *alle* Mitglieder einer Menge
gemacht wird, und *implizit*, weil der Quantor nicht mitgesprochen,
aber mitgemeint ist.

Dieser implizite Allquantor steht immer vor dem Subjekt, nicht
vor dem Gleichsetzungsnominativ. Die Frage ist also nun: Was
ist das Subjekt und was der Gleichsetzungsnominativ?
Prinzipiell ist im Deutschen die Satzstellung
frei; das Subjekt *kann* daher auch hinter "ist" bzw. "sind" stehen.
Beispielsweise ist sowohl in

> Wir sind Europäer.

als auch in

> Europäer sind wir.

das Pronomen "wir" das Subjekt und "Europäer" der
Gleichsetzungsnominativ.
Solange es allerdings keinen konkreten Grund (z.B., Grammatik, Bedeutung, Betonung, ...) gibt,
etwas anderes anzunehmen, interpretiert der deutsche Muttersprachler
einen Satz

> Bageduls sind Gamelafs.

immer so, daß das Subjekt an erster Stelle steht: "Bageduls" ist also das Subjekt,
"Gamelafs" der Gleichsetzungsnominativ. Das heißt aber,
der implizite Allquantor steht vor "Bageduls".
Durch Umstellung bekäme man

> Gamelafs sind Bageduls.

und da nun der implizite Allquantor ("alle")
vor dem mutmaßlichen Subjekt "Gamelafs" steht,
ändert sich die Bedeutung des Satzes.
Am konkreten Beispiel sieht man es sofort:

> Belgier sind Europäer.

ist offensichtlich richtig (gemeint ist "alle Belgier"!), aber

> Europäer sind Belgier.

ist (da jetzt ein implizites "alle" vor "Europäer" steht)
offensichtlich falsch.

Comment: Die Annahme, dass das erste Substantiv das Subjekt und das zweite das Prädikatsnomen sei, ist nicht immer richtig - "Mein Vater ist Arzt" und "Arzt ist mein Vater. [nicht etwa Automechaniker]" bedeuten dasselbe. Man kann das Prädikatsnomen durchaus zur Betonung nach vorne ziehen. Diese Form ist zugegebenermassen selten und nur vom Kontext abhängig erkennbar.

Comment: @tofro ok, "keinen grammatikalischen Grund" war zu eng. Ich hab's erweitert.

Answer (score 2):

Die Sätze im zweiten Beispiel haben definitiv die selbe Bedeutung. Bei den ersten Sätzen bin ich mir jedoch nicht so sicher. Dazu müsste man genauer wissen, ob es sich bei "Hunden" um Haushunde handelt. Falls das der Fall ist, ist die Bedeutung nicht mehr die Selbe, da Wölfe und Haushunde als unterschiedliche Gattungen wahrgenommen werden, und auch wohl Unterschiede im Erbgut aufweisen.

Mehr in der Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunde

Comment: Ich glaube, das war nur ein Beispiel, und es geht eher um die allegmeine Gleichsetzung und deren Umkehrung.

Comment: Habe mal ein Nachtrag hinzugefügt, da ich es jetzt erst selbst verstanden habe, was mich zu dieser Frage führte. Die Umkehrung vom Wolf/Hund Satz ist wohl nur für eine "Untermenge" korrekt.

Answer (score 2):

Im Prinzip ist *ist* mathematisch gesehen eine Äquivalenzrelation, also folgt aus `a=b` auch `b=a`.

Der erste Beispielsatz ist aber eine Zusammenziehung aus:

> Hunde sind durch das Zivilisieren von Wölfen entstanden.

Will man diesen Satz auf die Wölfe umstülpen, landet man bei

> Zivilisiert man Wölfe, werden [irgendwann] Hunde entstehen.

Für diesen Satz funktioniert die Zusammenziehung nicht.